# Map allowing to putIfAbsent without creating the value when key already exists

Tags: java, concurrency, dictionary, garbage

I'd like to use a map that would be equivalent to `ConcurrentMap` (I want the equivalent of the *putIfAbsent* method) but that would not force me to create the object beforehand.

For example when I do this:

```
m.putIfAbsent( key, new CyclingArray() );
```

I may end up creating a new *CyclingArray* (whatever that is) object for nothing.

Of course I realize I could lock up the entire map but that would be defeating the whole point of a `ConcurrentMap`.

Could something like the following work conceptually?

```
   m.putIfAbsent( key, new Callback<CyclingArray>() {
     @Override
     public CyclingArray provide() {
       return new CyclingArray();  // only called if the key wasn't already present
     }         
   }
```

Do you know of any library offering a map that:

1. offer an "interface" like the one offered by ConcurrentMap, including a `putIfAbsent` method.
2. does only lock on the segment we're going to work with (like the `ConcurrentHashMap` implementation does, for example)
3. allows to optionally create the value, if and only if the key wasn't already present and hence dodge useless garbage generation.
4. does not force me to use first a *containsKey* and then a *putIfAbsent* because this, also, somehow defeats the purpose of *putIfAbsent*.

Note that I'm **not** asking if the above example can be done with a `ConcurrentMap` (it cannot AFAIK).

I was thinking about extending `ConcurrentHashMap` and overloading *putIfAbsent* with the callback version but sadly `ConcurrentHashMap` internally uses a final *Segment* class.

Before re-inventing the wheel I'd like to know if there are any maps out there already offering a similar functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common use case you are looking for, its called memoization.  I would look at [MapMaker](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html)

You would be able to create a computingMap and put your creating function there:

```
 ConcurrentMap<Key, CyclingArray> graphs = new MapMaker()
       .concurrencyLevel(32)
       .makeComputingMap(
           new Function<Key, CyclingArray>() {
                public CyclingArray  apply(Key key) {
                    return new CyclingArray();  // only called if the key wasn't already    
                }              
           });
```

Here the `Function` will only be called if the `Key` is not present

And I do know future plans in Java have a computingMap type interface will come with standard Java, unfortunately at this point you will have to delegate to google-collections.

Comment: +1... But I've always used the term "memoization" to refer to caching on the fly of *results* of method calls:   *compute(17,24,59)* takes a long time to execute, store the result of that computation in a cache and reuse if upon cache hit.  I've never ever heard the term "memoization" used when trying to prevent needless object creation.  Here on Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization the definition and examples have nothing to do with object creation.  I may be mistaken but I find it a bit weird to call this "memoization" : )

Comment: Just to be clear: using a callback here to dodge object creation is inherently working around a Java "feature" (let's call it that way).  So it's true that we may end up more or less reusing the result of a method call but in my idea memoization as always been about using the parameters of a method call to compute on-the-fly a key and store the result in a cache (as opposed to dynamic programming, which typically cache *in advance* all possible resuls).